# Como remover caracteres a direita de uma string javascript caso encontre determinado caractere

Tags: javascript

Uma string chamada minhaString recebe o valor abaixo:

```
minhaString = 'O dependente DEPENDENTE não foi cadastrado. 
Erro: A coluna 'NOME' não pertence à tabela PFDEPENDCOMPL. 
======================================= em 
System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
```

> Quero remover todos os caracteres a partir da seguinte sequencia de caracteres 
>   '======================================='

para que a string fique assim:

```
minhaString = 'O dependente DEPENDENTE não foi cadastrado. 
Erro: A coluna 'NOME' não pertence à tabela PFDEPENDCOMPL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que a variável `minhaString` contenha valor, ficaria assim:

```
var novaString = minhaString.substr(0, minhaString.indexOf('='));
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente esse método

Comment: Por nada camarada, tmj!